# Must cookies contain chocolate in BrE?

Tags: british-english, nuance, food

In British English, my friend informed me that my use of the word *cookie* was incorrect in referring to a baked item having no chocolate bits in it. Instead the appropriate term would have to be *biscuit*, as *cookie* always required some form of chocolate to be inside the biscuit.

Is this assertion correct?

The Oxford dictionary only [explains](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cookie) the meaning in American English, not British English: "A sweet biscuit."

In case this is relevant, the object in question was a slightly sweet ginger-biscuit/cookie.

Comment: As an AmEng speaker, I can't answer this question directly - but I can tell you that the "object in question" is called a "ginger snap" in AmEng (at least if it's baked to be crunchy - soft-baked ginger cookies are just called "ginger cookies", or "Gingeroos" if you buy them at Trader Joe's.)  I believe that what we call "ginger snaps" are known as "ginger nuts" in BrEng and AussieEng.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger_nut

Comment: As you're no doubt aware, in AmEng "cookie" is applied to (just about) all* small, sweet pastries, with or without chocolate; "biscuit", in fact, generally refers only to UNsweetened biscuits.  This occasionally leads to confusion.

Comment: I _never_ asked myself this question when wondering about letting a website leave cookies on my computer...

Comment: @oerkelens: Just think of how the [internet would be](https://c1.staticflickr.com/7/6167/6245153744_55f81cd83d_z.jpg) if the people at Netscape would have been British :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Until recently, *cookie* was a foreign word in British English: because of American TV and films, most people knew that it was American for *biscuit*.

*Cookie* is now familiar for the large, sweet, not-very-crunchy confections sold in shopping malls. They come in various flavours, and don't have to have chocolate.

I don't think anybody I know would call traditional-style English biscuits (whether Bath Oliver, Malted Milk, Garibaldi, Ginger nut, Fig roll, or even Hobnob) "cookies".

Comment: Since the [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/biscuit?q=biscuit) defines *biscuit* as *A small baked unleavened cake, typically **crisp,** flat, and sweet*, is crispness the difference between a *cookie* and a *biscuit* in the U.K.?

Comment: No, or not entirely. Biscuits are far more varied than cookies, and some of them are distinctly less crunchy than cookies (eg [fig rolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fig_roll)).

Comment: I think very few native speakers of English -- British or American -- would describe fig rolls as a type of biscuit. They belong in their own separate category.

Comment: @ErikKowal: [Wikipedia does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fig_rolls)

Comment: I'm unconvinced that fig rolls are biscuits, no matter what Wikipedia says, but we get both crisp and chewy 'cookies' in the UK.

Comment: @ErikKowal. You may be right, but fig rolls were certainly biscuits in our home when I was a child. Oddly, the GloWbE corpus has five instances of "fig roll", but they're all from Irish sources rather than UK ones. One of the five is explicitly "fig roll biscuits".

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, in British English, a cookie *is* a biscuit, just a specific kind.

As a British English speaker, I would say cookies don't have to include chocolate, although they usually do.  I would go further and say that cookies have a very specific meaning here - they are round, flat and contain *chips* (typically chocolate).  If there are no chips, but are covered in chocolate then they are simply a chocolate biscuit.

So, these are cookies, irrespective of whether they are crisp or chewy:

[image: Cookies]

I did try to find an image of cookies without chocolate chips (e.g just nuts), but they invariably do contain chocolate, although sometimes white.  Nevertheless I believe a macadamia chip cookie *just* about qualifies

Whereas, these are chocolate biscuits.

[image: Chocolate biscuits]

And this is an ordinary biscuit

[image: biscuit]

And this non-cookie status for chocolate biscuits also extends to sandwich style biscuits, so this is not a cookie either:
[image]

And incidentally the above image is far inferior to this UK delight [image: Bourbon]

Comment: You can get cookies that don't have chocolate in them though. What about macademia nut cookies, for example? If containing chocolate chips were a requirement for being called a cookie, then it would be redundant to have "chocolate chip cookies".

Comment: I stand corrected, I forgot about those.  I suppose the definition is "chips".  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Although if you then added raisins, then all bets are off.  That's not a cookie is it?  Even though I've made the edit, I'm still not entirely convinced that you can have a cookie without chocolate chips, especially since I couldn't actually find any in an image search!

Comment: We do have raisin cookies too. https://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/oatmeal-raisin-cookies/238adb0d-af3e-4abf-a131-060eeff34d10

Comment: @JohnClifford That's a bridge too far for me.

Comment: I think soft cookies can get away without chips, but if crispy they have to have *chocolate* chips or they're biscuits (and chocolate chip biscuits are possible)

Comment: @ChrisH Sounds like a soft biscuit to me.  I don't think I'd immediately recognise what you've described as a cookie.